# Nitro PDF Express removing already outputted files when I cancel it

Tags: pdf, conversion, documents

Im converting lots of .doc files into .pdf using Nitro PDF Express. The program isn't finish converting the 37 files yet maybe 10 are converted and are in the output directory already. 
But when I cancelled it, even the converted one's are deleted. Can I still find it somewhere or are they gone for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recovery program like http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: yup tried that , but all the files are in bad shape/corrupted

Answer (score 2):

Start the conversion again, and copy the files before stopping the program?